# Chapter with graphical formatting

Tags: graphics, numbering, chapters, titlesec

I am formatting a book and I am using LuaLaTex. I am trying to obtain the following formatting for the chapters, 
[image: reproduction of the chapter number and title]

The following code correctly generates the chapter title

```
\usepackage{titlesec}

%Chapter heading
\newfontfamily\chapterfont[Color=black]{Avenir Light}% set font

\titlespacing{\chapter}% {left}{before}{after}[right]
{50pt}%left
{3ex plus 2ex}%before
{1.7cm}%after

\titleformat{\chapter}% command to be modified
  {\fontsize{24}{27}\bfseries\scshape\chapterfont} %format
  {\thechapter.}% label
  {1em}% sep
  {} % before-code
  [{\color{red}\titlerule[1pt]}] % after-code
```

but I cannot find a way to make the graphical chapter number, and also to extend the red rule to the right page border. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A solution based on `tcolorbox` package

---

```
% !TeX program = lualatex                                   
% !TeX encoding = utf8
\documentclass[14pt]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[
    a4paper,
    left=2cm,
    right=2cm,
    top=2.5cm,
    bottom=2cm,
]{geometry}

\newtcbox{\mychapternum}{enhanced,nobeforeafter,tcbox raise base,boxrule=1pt,top=0mm,bottom=0mm,
  colframe=cyan,coltext=cyan,colback=cyan!10!white, halign = right,
    width=50pt,arc=7mm, sharp corners=west, boxsep=4mm,
    overlay={\draw[thick] ([yshift=3ex]frame.north west) -- ([yshift=-3ex]frame.south west);

      }
  }  

%Chapter heading
%\newfontfamily\chapterfont[Color=black]{Avenir Light}% set font
\titlespacing{\chapter}% {left}{before}{after}[right]
{60pt}%left
{1ex plus 2ex}%before
{1.7cm}%after

\titleformat{\chapter}% command to be modified
  {\fontsize{24}{27}\bfseries\scshape} %format
  {\hspace*{-70pt}
    \mychapternum{\thechapter}
    }% label
  {0em}% sep
  {} % before-code
  [{\color{red}
    \begingroup
      \setlength{\titlewidth}{\textwidth}
      \titleline*{\titlerule[1pt]}
    \endgroup  
    }] % after-code

\begin{document}


\chapter{My title}

\lipsum[20-30]

\chapter{My title}

\lipsum[20-30]
\end{document}
```

[image]

A solution based on `TikZ` package. This solution more flexible for adjustemets.

---

```
% !TeX program = lualatex                                   
% !TeX encoding = utf8    
\documentclass[14pt]{book}      
\usepackage{fontspec}      
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc, positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}   
\usepackage[
    a4paper,
    left=2cm,
    right=2cm,
    top=2.5cm,
    bottom=2cm,
]{geometry}   
%Chapter heading
%\newfontfamily\chapterfont[Color=black]{Avenir Light}% set font
\titlespacing{\chapter}% {left}{before}{after}[right]
{2cm}%left
{2ex}%before
{1.7cm}%after

\titleformat{\chapter}% command to be modified
  {\Huge\bfseries\scshape} %format
  {\hspace*{-1cm}
      \tikz [anchor=base, baseline,remember picture, overlay]{%
        \node[line width = 2pt, draw=cyan, fill =cyan!10, anchor=base, rectangle,  text width=2cm, align=right, rounded rectangle,rounded rectangle west arc=5pt, minimum height=4ex,
           inner sep=11pt] (A)
              {\color{cyan}\thechapter};
    \draw[line width = 2.5pt] ([yshift=3ex]A.north west) -- ([yshift=-3ex]A.south west);
    \draw[line width = 1pt, red] let \p1=(A.south east), \p2=(current page.east) in  ([xshift=2.6ex]A.south east) -- +(\x2,0);
    }%
    }% label
  {\dimexpr2em\relax}% sep
  {} % before-code
  [] % after-code

\begin{document}
\chapter{My title}
\lipsum[20-30]
\addtocounter{chapter}{20}
\chapter{My title}
\lipsum[20-30]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Would you also be able to tell me how I can extend the red rule to the right page margin instead that to the right of \textwidth?

Comment: @pierocol instead `{\color{red}\titlerule[1pt]}` put `{\color{red}\rule{\dimexpr5pt+\textwidth\relax}{0.2pt}}`

Comment: thank you thank you thank you! However, with this command, there is a rather large vertical space between the text of the chapter title and the red rule. Any clue?

Comment: I do not understand your question, sorry. I would like the chapter title to look like in the picture that I posted, which shows the top of a page, therefore from the left to the right border of the page. The red rule therefore should be aligned with the bottom of the lower side of the blue shape

Comment: @pierocol I had changed code.

Comment: Now I will try to understand all these commands, because I need to customise some more. In case I will ask more questions. Thanks

Comment: I do not understand how can I set the dimensions of the blue box. In order to reproduce my example, the box must be wider, and the chapter number must be moved more to the right.

Comment: @pierocol I had added  another solution.

Comment: This is even better

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86508/discussion-between-pierocol-and-sergiokapone).

Comment: I cannot find anywhere  an explanation of what \dimexpr2em\relax  does. May i ask you to elucidate?

Comment: @pierocol You can use instead `\dimexpr2em\relax` just 2em, or what you want.

Comment: yes, I have tried that and it works, however I just wanted to learn something new and wondered what \dimexpr2em\relax does

Comment: One of the chapters is long therefore I have to break it and have it on two lines. The red line under the chapter title remains under the first line. Is there a way to position it always under the last row of the chapter title?